# nfs mount failing to reconnect after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, mount, fstab

Ok, this one is odd.  I just rebooted my entire home network for the first time.  Took a bit but got everything to come back up.  I have a media vault nas, sharing a handful of drives on NFS/SMB, and an old beater Ubuntu machine.

Now my nas came up no problem.  then my imac connected to the nas with SMB and all that came up.

Then i booted my ubuntu box.  First the IP changed, so i switched it to static and got all the services to start again.  But then i noticed that the drives weren't mounted  when i went to the mount points, i was a bit surprised to see this

```
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K Oct  2 21:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4.0K Aug  2 03:06 ..
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Jul  3 18:44 datastorage01
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Aug  2 04:06 movies01
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Aug  2 04:06 movies02
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Jul 20 21:46 tv01
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Aug  2 04:06 tv02
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Sep 12 22:10 tv03
```

those permissions aren't right.  I check mount

```
mediavault:/tv01 on /mnt/tv01 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.13)
mediavault:/tv02 on /mnt/tv02 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.13)
mediavault:/movies02 on /mnt/movies02 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.13)
mediavault:/movies01 on /mnt/movies01 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.13)
mediavault:/tv03 on /mnt/tv03 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.13)
mediavault:/datastorage01 on /mnt/datastorage01 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.5,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.13)
```

everything looks right.

ive rebooted the ubuntu box several times in the past, this never happened.

I have tried changing the permissions on the folder manually but i get "operation not permitted", even as root.  Im stumped.

here's my fstab

```
mediavault:/movies01  /mnt/movies01  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
mediavault:/movies02  /mnt/movies02  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
mediavault:/tv03  /mnt/tv03  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
mediavault:/tv01  /mnt/tv01  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
mediavault:/tv02  /mnt/tv02  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
mediavault:/datastorage01  /mnt/datastorage01  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

i even checked the server

```
$ showmount -e mediavault
Export list for mediavault:
/export               *
/export/tv03          *
/export/datastorage01 *
/export/movies02      *
/export/movies01      *
/export/tv02          *
/export/tv01          *
```

i can't for the life of me figure out whats wrong.  Even my boot log says it mounted properly.  Im stumped, any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to properly mount  when you manually from the command line?

Comment: No.  i unmount, chmod 775 on the mountpoint, then mount again and it goes back to 700

Comment: You cannot change the directory permission from the client side when it is mounted.  umount  first on the client side and then change the directory permission on *mediavault* .  Then mount again.